# Clion + STM32L1xx - how to setup

Tags: arm, stm32, clion, cortex-m

Before that I tried IDE Keil and she work but as IDE it's terrible.
So I'm trying to use CLion 2016.3 to build an embedded C++ project for an STM32L100RCx target on Ubuntu 16.04. But I can't undestand how to setup correctly. Reading the Jetbrain's blog doesn't help me. After compilation there is some error's that it can't find some call's from *.ld file.
Cmake flags:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb" "-msoft-float -mfix-cortex-m3-ldrd")
```

And got an errors:

```
/tmp/ccPo0ceQ.s:713: Error: selected processor does not support `dsb 0xF' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccPo0ceQ.s:734: Error: selected processor does not support `dsb 0xF' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccPo0ceQ.s:1100: Error: selected processor does not support `dsb 0xF' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccPo0ceQ.s:1111: Error: selected processor does not support `isb 0xF' in ARM mode
/tmp/ccPo0ceQ.s:1157: Error: selected processor does not support `dmb 0xF' in ARM mode
*** recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Project.elf.dir/Drivers/STM32L1xx_HAL_Driver/Src/stm32l1xx_hal_cortex.c.obj' failed
```

Can any one help me or may be get me working CMakeLists.txt and *.cmake files?

UPD:

My Cmake file:

```
include(CMakeForceCompiler)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)

CMAKE_FORCE_C_COMPILER(/opt/arm/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc GNU)
CMAKE_FORCE_CXX_COMPILER(/opt/arm/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++ GNU)

SET(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-mcpu=cortex-m3 -mthumb" "-msoft-float -mfix-cortex-m3-ldrd")

# fix long strings (CMake appends semicolons)
string(REGEX REPLACE ";" " " CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}")

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS}" CACHE STRING "")

set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${COMMON_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${COMMON_FLAGS} -std=gnu99")
set(LINKER_SCRIPT ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/STM32L100RCTx_FLASH.ld)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-Wl,-gc-sections -T ${LINKER_SCRIPT}")
```

Comment: Are you using the correct cross-compiler? Did you [set up the toolchain correctly](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html)?

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will read later.

Comment: I assume you set `COMMON_FLAGS` in the `CmakeForceCompiler.cmake` file? Otherwise it's unset and empty. And you set `CMAKE_C_FLAGS` multiple times to different values.

Comment: Now I have: 
 In function `exit':
exit.c:(.text.exit+0x16): undefined reference to `_exit

Answer (score 0):

It seems I find the right way.
My wrong sequence of actions:

- doing 'Reset Cache And Reload Project'
- then I try to build the project

I thought that the 'Reset Cache And Reload Project' is just cleaning the Cmake cache, but in fact it looks as if it is deleting some necessary files.

The sequence was correct:

- doing 'Reset Cache And Reload Project'
- doing 'Reload Cmake Project'
- then a successful build

In general, it was just enough to check the 'Automaticaly Reload Cmake Project on Edit' option.